# accepts_nested_attributes_for undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use accepts_nested_attributes to create a complex form. Based on the [Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) documentation, [examples](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes), etc., I've set up the models like so:

User model:

```
require 'digest'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, 
                  :password_confirmation, :ducks_attributes

  has_many :ducks, :class_name => 'Duck'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ducks
  .
  .
  .
end
```

Duck model:

```
class Duck < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

But when I try to access the nested attributes in the console, I get

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003 > User.first.ducks_attributes
NoMethodError: undefined method `ducks_attributes' for #<User:0x007ffc63e996e0>
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:392:in `method_missing'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:46:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):3
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the attribute **writer** is defined.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ducks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ducks
end

class Duck < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

# This works:
User.first.ducks_attributes = [ { :name => "Donald" } ]

# This is more common (attributes posted from a form):
User.create :ducks_attributes => [ { :name => "Donald" }, { :name => "Dewey" } ]
```